# AngularJS - How to cancel a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, deferred

Let's say I have an input text field (more like the Google search field) which, when changed, will trigger a request and show some results.

For instance,

Let's type in `Dog` in the input:

```
typed D -> Calls ctrl.search('D') -> Makes a request -> Changes model when success
typed DO -> Calls ctrl.search('DO') -> Makes a request -> Changes model when success
typed DOG -> Calls ctrl.search('DOG') -> Makes a request -> Changes model when success.
```

Now, let's say that the `DO` request responds later than the `DOG` one. My model would end up with the `DO` results, even if I typed `DOG`.

For that, I need a way to cancel or abort current ongoing requests if I keep on typing characters. That way, my model is only changed by the final request.

My input looks like the following:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="query" data-ng-change="ctrl.search(query)" placeholder="Search" />
```

Here is my `searchCtrl.js`:

```
var search;
var language;
var _this;

var SearchCtrl = function (searchService, lang)
{
     search = searchService;
     langauge = lang;
     _this = this;
}

SearchCtrl.prototype.search = function (text)
{
    var promise = search.language(language)
                  .facet('characters')
                  .highlight('quotes')
                  .query(text);

    promise.then(function (response) {
         if(!response) return;
         _this.total = response.total;
         _this.count = response.found;
         _this.result = response.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: We can't cancel promise..either we need to `reject` or `resolve` it to complete it..

Comment: 1) Use debounce in your textbox you can use ng-model-options 2) You can provide a promise to the timeout property of http option which you can cancel it (by rejecting that deferred object), but the request will still be processed by the server it will just be rejected at the client level.

Comment: It would likely be better to solve this by not sending the request in the first place until a short pause in typing has occurred. Canceling the request won't stop the server from processing it if it has already received it. look into https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions specfically the debounce option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually for this case people use `ng-model-options={debounce: 100}`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

anyway you can reject promise.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you very much! Is this like a delay before sending each request?

Comment: yes, it helps you ;) u're welcome.

Comment: @MatiasCicero it's basically a timeout that gets reset every time the value changes. so, if the value stops changing for 100ms, the timer ends and a request is sent.

Comment: This still doesn't solve your original problem... If a delayed "DO" returns later than an even further delayed "DOG", it will still use the "DO" results. All you are doing is saving the call to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use a `debounce` technique in this case?

see:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions
- http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/12/increasing-angular-performance-by-debouncing-your-ng-model-updates/

  ```
  <input type="text"
     class="form-control" 
     data-ng-model="query" 
     data-ng-change="ctrl.search(query)" 
     placeholder="Search" 
     ng-model-options="{ debounce: { 'default': 500,  'blur': 0 } }"    
  />
  ```

Comment: Thank you! What does `'blur': 0` do?

Comment: I copied that from the docs, might be not needed in your case, when leaving the field it would not have the debounce delay (because it is 0), you can fine tune the debounce based on each event type if desired

Answer (score 0):

Like this: `$q.reject(response);`

Although technically I believe that the above commenter is correct, you're actually rejecting the promise and not really canceling it.

Comment: Wouldn't that reject my final request too? What would be the logic to abort only a request if the user is still typing?

Comment: I answered before I fully grocked your code example, the debounce answer above is a better method to address your need.